# How to show that $\mathbb{E}(\sup_{0\le t\le1} |B(t)|)<\infty $?

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, brownian-motion

How to show that for the standard Brownian motion $B(t)$, we have
$$\mathbb{E}(\sup_{0\le t\le1} |B(t)|)<\infty
$$

Comment: Apply [Doob's Martingale inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doob%27s_martingale_inequality).

Comment: @Surb Thanks. So we have $P(\sup_{0\le t\le T} |B(t)|>C)\to 0$ as $T\to \infty$. How to use this to conclude the desired result?

Comment: Look rather at the part "further inequalities".

Comment: Seems like the reflection principle should also be applicable here.

Comment: $\vert B(t)\vert\le(1+\vert B(t)\vert^2)/2$, and you can use Doob's martingale inequality with $p=2$